# How to type curly braces on an Apple keyboard with BootCamp, running Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, boot-camp

How do I type a curly brace, the "{"? I run Windows 7 on BootCamp with an Apple keyboard.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>does not appear to work.

Comment: they are normally called curly braces or brackets.  However, I like the term squiggly brackets...

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/343937/how-to-make-braces-with-apple-keyboard-in-windows/345273#345273

Comment: @user99572isfine - Good find.  Between two answers its basically the answer I posted.  Shocked my research didn't locate that question.

Answer (score 1):

If the shortcut is not working I would just configure the keyboard [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5636)

If you are looking for a [keyboard combination](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3974-making-an-open-close-brace-on-a-mac-keyboard) might work

I would like to point out that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> even on a Windows Keyboard does not generate a left curly bracket.  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> does